# React adding an element programmatically with a HOC

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

Is there a way using a High Order Component to add elements programatically to a Component? I was wondering if there was a way using `React.createElement` to append the component's children? Here is the code that I have so far:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

function addAnElement(WrappedComponent) {

  return class Enhancer extends WrappedComponent {

    render() {

      const elementsTree = super.render()

      // Programatically add a child? 
      // Update elementTree.props.children somehow?

      return elementsTree
    }
  }
}


class JustSomeText extends Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <p>A long time ago, in a galaxy far, far away.</p>
        {/* I want to add an element here? */}
      </div>
    )
  }
}


function App() {

  const ExtendedComponent = addAnElement(JustSomeText)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ExtendedComponent />      
    </div>
  )
}

export default App

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

I'm also interested in other, more effective ways to achieving the same result.

Comment: Rendering an array perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to achieve this (although it does not use HOC) is using the `children` prop in React.

```
class JustSomeText extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>A long time ago, in a galaxy far, far away.</p>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <JustSomeText>
         <p>more text!</p>
      </JustSomeText>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This will render the following:

```
<div className="App">
   <div>
      <p>A long time ago, in a galaxy far, far away.</p>
      <p>more text!</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Refer to this for further detail on `children` - https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html